# C# Changing the existing Firefox Profile location in selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I have created a new user profile(`In Run, type -> firefox.exe -p and create a new profile`). For demo purpose I have created a new folder on my desktop. My new user profile points to this new location `(C:\Users\username\Desktop\TemporaryProfile)`. In my selenium webdriver i want to change the default location of the firefox profile.

```
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla   Firefox\firefox.exe");
  FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(@"C:\Users\username\Desktop\TemporaryProfile");                                
  FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);
```

In the preceding code, it is not taking the new firefox profile location rather it is taking the existing one. I mean the default location.

And `FireFoxProfile` Class has a property named `profileDirectory`. But unfortunately it is a get property

```
public string ProfileDirectory { get; }
```

So I couldn't be able to set the directory location.

How to change the firefox profile location in selenium webdriver? Whenever my script executes it should not take the default profile location rather it should point to the new user profile location. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to change profile:

```
var option = new FirefoxOptions();
var profile = new FirefoxProfile("Path_to_profile");
option.Profile = profile;
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(option);
```